# Is it possible to list all the global options that can be set for a package?

Tags: r, package

From the vignette of [tibble](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/vignettes/tibble.html), I read that some changes can be made in global options through `options` to control the appearance of printing. However, I failed to find any manual for this options with in R. I even cannot known what fields can be added to global options for a package. So the question is:

For a package, can we get a list of fields (like `tibble.print_max`, `tibble.print_min` for `tibble` and `BioC_mirror` for `utils`) that can be set through `options` with in R before knowing them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given the lack of required practice (e.g., on CRAN) for how to handle options in external (or even internal, as far as I can tell) packages, perhaps the most general approach is like this:

1. Find the package on the [CRAN mirror on GitHub](https://github.com/cran). For example, here's [`tibble`](https://github.com/cran/tibble).
2. Search for "option" within the repository to find [all references to "option" in the package's code](https://github.com/cran/tibble/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=option&type=).
3. Search through this. It takes a bit of a keen eye to know what to look for, but this is how I learned that all of `tibble`'s options are listed on the main package help page (`?"tibble-package"`), because I found [these lines](https://github.com/cran/tibble/blob/8691b6d1439787d36698913517f72e97aa4104a7/R/tibble.R#L29-L50) with the search.

Step 3 can be automated better if you clone the repo to your machine and use command line tools, e.g.

```
cd package_dir
grep option R/*
```

(this is quite similar to the above, but enables the full flexibility of `grep`)

Just for additional confirmation, this approach led me to the right place for [`data.table`](https://github.com/cran/data.table/blob/608958201639620bb5bf5b6fd5d438d95e58e2ce/R/onLoad.R#L30-L50) and [`xtable`](https://github.com/cran/xtable/blob/d2161904474544167c6ee9dce42e521ce63fcb28/man/print.xtable.Rd#L10-L44) as well.

Answer (score 8):

The way settable options are handled is at the discretion of the package author (whether they include them in `.Options`, keep them hidden, etc.).  It looks like the *tibble* package has a hidden variable `op.tibble`, which shows the available options.

```
tibble:::op.tibble
# $tibble.print_max
# [1] 20
# 
# $tibble.print_min
# [1] 10
#
# $tibble.width
# NULL
#
# $tibble.max_extra_cols
# [1] 100
```

So the following will give you the names of available options in the package.

```
names(tibble:::op.tibble)
# [1] "tibble.print_max"      "tibble.print_min"     
# [3] "tibble.width"          "tibble.max_extra_cols"
```

As a note, I found `op.tibble` by doing

```
grep("op", ls(getNamespace("tibble"), all=TRUE), value=TRUE)
# [1] "op.tibble"  "stopc"      "tibble_opt"
```

and then looking at those items individually.  Perhaps other authors might do something similar.  But there is no general rule for defining options in packages.

Comment: Also `?"tibble-package"` lists these. But the more general question of "given some random package `foo`, how can I tell which `options` it has available" -- I don't know that there's a consistent answer to that.

Comment: @MichaelChirico - No, there isn't because package authors can do whatever they want with options.

Comment: Right, which seems like it's not the best practice... it does seem like a useful  thing to know when exploring the capabilities of a new package... we know where to find all the manual pages, but options may get dusty if they're not easy to find

Comment: Knowing about these options will be helpful under certain circumstances. But it seems there is not a general way to do this.